# Until when did Russia occupy Paris after 1814

Tags: france, napoleonic-wars

Russia occupied Paris in 1814 after the battle of Paris. They supposedly stayed for a while, I heard the anecdote that the word 'bistro' derives from that time (not generally accepted in linguistics it seems, but I have a different opinion). So the question is: when did Russia end the occupation?

Comment: Please include the details of your research so far (to avoid others covering the same ground).

Answer (score 11):

It would appear the 1814 occupation of Paris lasted for 2 months, beginning on March 31,1814, the culmination of the [Battle of Paris](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Battle_of_Paris_(1814)#:%7E:text=On%20March%2031%20Talleyrand%20gave%20the%20key%20of%20the%20city%20to%20the%20Tsar.%20Later%20that%20day%20the%20Coalition%20armies%20triumphantly%20entered%20the%20city%20with%20the%20Tsar%20at%20the%20head%20of%20the%20army%20followed%20by%20the%20King%20of%20Prussia%20and%20Prince%20Schwarzenberg.)

> On March 31 Talleyrand gave the key of the city to the Tsar. Later
> that day the Coalition armies triumphantly entered the city with the
> Tsar at the head of the army followed by the King of Prussia and
> Prince Schwarzenberg.

...and ending on June 1, 1814, with the signing of the First [Treaty of Paris](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Treaty_of_Paris_(1814)#:%7E:text=The%20Treaty%20of,followed%20in%201815.)
signaling the official cessation of hostilities.

> The Treaty of Paris, signed on 30 May 1814, ended the war between
> France and the Sixth Coalition, part of the Napoleonic Wars, following
> an armistice signed on 23 April between Charles, Count of Artois, and
> the allies.[1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Battle_of_Paris_(1814)#:%7E:text=On%20March%2031%20Talleyrand%20gave%20the%20key%20of%20the%20city%20to%20the%20Tsar.%20Later%20that%20day%20the%20Coalition%20armies%20triumphantly%20entered%20the%20city%20with%20the%20Tsar%20at%20the%20head%20of%20the%20army%20followed%20by%20the%20King%20of%20Prussia%20and%20Prince%20Schwarzenberg.) The treaty set the borders for France under the House
> of Bourbon and restored territories to other nations. It is sometimes
> called the First Peace of Paris, as another one followed in 1815.

From pp 134 of the book [*Securing Europe after Napoleon*](https://books.google.com/books?id=xGjtDwAAQBAJ&pg=PA134&dq=napoleon%20Allies%20left%20on%201%20june&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjqz_6m2Zv1AhXgIDQIHRr_Dk8QuwV6BAgJEAY#v=onepage&q=napoleon%20Allies%20left%20on%201%20june&f=false)*: 1815 and the New European Security Culture*, edited by Beatrice de Graaf, Ido de Haan, Brian Vick we get a summary of the timeline (emphasis mine):

> The Council had a precursor in the occupation of 1814 that included
> two phases: a *war occupation* (from the time that the Allied forces
> crossed the French border and seized areas around the turn of the year
> December 1813-March 1814) and a *truce occupation* (*from the end of
> March **until the Allies left on 1 June 1814***)

So after the Treaty of Paris was signed 30 May,1814 the Allies withdrew on **June 1, 1814**.